# Can I use a bayesian spatio-temporal model in cluster areas I chose from local Moran's I?

Tags: bayesian, clustering, spatio-temporal

I have crime rates for municipalities in a state with hourly frequency. I want to make predictions about the spatio-temporal behavior of that variable. Is it possible to run a local Moran's I to detect state clusters and then apply a bayesian spatio-temporal model for high-high clusters? If not, how should I proceed to find clusters?